# LiveAgent - StartChatWithWindow: wrong Chat Page

Tags: visualforce, liveagent, startchat

I have set up a Live Agent.
Suppose a chat has begun between a client and the operator. At the end of this chat the operator ha the chance to give to the client a link that he can use in another moment to reconnect with the same Operator. The link is done is this way:
http://mySite.com/CP_RicollegamentoChatEsistente?idUtentetramiteURL=00525000000EbDQ

CP_RicollegamentoChatEsistente is a Visualforce page that implements the connection with a liveagent with a specific user:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false"  cache="true" controller="CP_RicollegamentoChatEsistenteController" >  

<head>Redirecting page</head> 



<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la1-c1cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/34.0/deployment.js'></script>

<script>

    //------------------------------------------------- 
    liveagent.addCustomDetail("&$£&%"$£/!$£/");    
    liveagent.findOrCreate("Info__c").map("ID_AOL__c", "IdAOL", false, false,true);
    ...........  bla bla bla, stuff I have to take care .............
 liveagent.findOrCreate("Survey_Operatore__c").saveToTranscript("Survey_Operatore__c","Survey_Operatore__c");

     // DEPLOYMENT 
    liveagent.init('https://d.la1-c1cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572250000008OKV', '00D25000000DJeh');

     // BUTTON
     setTimeout(function(){ 
        //liveagent.startChatWithWindow('573250000008OLT', 'ChatWindow','{! idUtente}', true); THIS CALLS THE LIVEAGENT STANDARD CHAT

        liveagent.startChat('573250000008OLT', '{! idUtente}', true); // LIVEAGENT STANDARD CHAT  
        //liveagent.startChat('573250000008OLT'); THIS WOULD CALL THE CUSTOM 'CHATWINDOW'
     },2000);  

    // Javascript URL redirection
    // window.location.replace("http://andreaianni.branded.me/");

</script> 


<!-- Stuff necessary for the liveagent -->

<a id="liveagent_button_online_573250000008OLT" href="javascript://Chat" style="display: none;" onclick="liveagent.startChat('573250000008OLT')"> <!-- Online Chat Content  -->
</a>
<div id="liveagent_button_offline_573250000008OLT" style="display: none;"><!-- Offline Chat Content --></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
window._laq.push(function(){liveagent.showWhenOnline('573250000008OLT', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_573250000008OLT'));
liveagent.showWhenOffline('573250000008OLT', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_573250000008OLT'));
});</script>

<!-- End Stuff -->

</apex:page>
```

The Deployment is the following:

[image]

The Button is done as follows:
[image]

Summarizing: why does the startChat without the user Id redirects rightly and the startChat with the user Id doesn not?

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a bug in the startChat() method - the method does not seem to function correctly with the 18-character user Id but does seem to work using the 15-character version. startChat() with the user Id should redirect correctly once you've made this change in your `idUtente` variable.

liveagent.startChat('573250000008OLT', '{! idUtente}', true);

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @crmprogdev I edited the answer to clarify. Thanks.